# Are EF4 classes really POCO?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4

I'm starting to study EF4 as a possible replacementt for NH in my new projects. I'm interested in an object-first developement. I found a tutorial that drive me in creating a designer surface and draw my entities here... the resulting entities are *plenty* of attributes ( are this POCO ? ), so what I ask is:
Is there some way to use EF4 by writing the entities in code, whitout dragging and designi, plus creating and *updating* the database ? Some tutorial/blog ?

Comment: It seems to me that "POCO" has come to mean: "not derived from a specified library" class; and not "no library defined interfaces/attributes". But from some initial definitions of POCO one could get the impression it is the latter.

Comment: at least should be "not mandatory derived from...", shouldn't ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF offers several ways to create your entities. First is simply using designer and let it generate classes for you as "code behind" of the designer. These ones are heavy entities - no POCOs. Second approach is to use designer but turn auto generation off. Instead you will use [POCO T4 template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/02/18/entity-framework-poco-template-updated-for-visual-studio-2010-release-candidate.aspx) which will create real POCOs for you (you can also create [POCOs by yourselves](http://devtalk.dk/2009/05/22/Entity+Framework+40+How+To+POCO.aspx) but you have to [follow strict rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456872.aspx) - expecially if you want to use lazy loading). The last option is to use new [Code-First approach](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/06/ef-feature-ctp5-code-first-walkthrough.aspx) wich is not part of EF itself - it is in [CTP5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=35adb688-f8a7-4d28-86b1-b6235385389d) currently. This approach let you define POCO classes and use fluent API or attributes to map them.

Comment: so we have to wait for a production version of the code first approach to have something comparable to NH

Comment: I'm happy with designer and template at the moment and I'm playing with Code-First on hobby projects.

Answer (score 2):

There's a fairly comprehensive tutorial on [Julie Lerman's blog](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/agile-entity-framework-4-repository-part-1-model-and-poco-classes/) about EF4 and POCO classes.  It may have what you're looking for.